# Learning python for security, having trouble with su

Tags: python, linux, security

Preface: I am fully aware that this could be illegal if not on a test machine. I am doing this as a learning exercise for learning python for security and penetration testing. This will ONLY be done on a linux machine that I own and have full control over.

I am learning python as my first scripting language hopefully for use down the line in a security position. Upon asking for ideas of scripts to help teach myself, someone suggested that I create one for user enumeration.The idea is simple, cat out the user names from /etc/passwd from an account that does NOT have sudo privileges and try to 'su' into those accounts using the one password that I have. A reverse brute force of sorts, instead of a single user with a list of passwords, Im using a single password with a list of users.

My issue is that no matter how I have approached this, the script hangs or stops at the "Password: " prompt. I have tried multiple methods, from using os.system and echoing the password in, passing it as a variable, and using the pexpect module. Nothing seems to be working.

When I Google it, all of the recommendations point to using sudo, which in this scenario, isnt a valid option as the user I have access to, doesnt have sudo privileges.

I am beyond desperate on this, just to finish the challenge. I have asked on reddit, in IRC and all of my programming wizard friends, and beyond echo "password" |sudo -S su, which cant work because the user is not in the sudoers file, I am coming up short. When I try the same thing with just echo "password"| su  I get su: must be run from a terminal. This is at a # and $ prompt.

Is this even possible?

Comment: you'll need to open a "pseudo-teletype" or Pty device through which to communicate with"su…"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `su` and friends read the password directly from the controlling terminal for the process, not from stdin. The way to get around this is to launch your own "pseudoterminal" (`pty`). In python, you can do that with [the `pty` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html). Give it a try.

**Edit:** The documentation for python's `pty` module doesn't really explain anything, so here's a bit of context from the Unix man page for the `pty` device:

> A pseudo terminal is a pair of character devices, a master
>        device and a slave device.  The slave device provides to a process an
>        interface identical to that described in tty(4).  However, whereas all
>        other devices which provide the interface described in tty(4) have a
>        hardware device of some sort behind them, the slave device has, instead,
>        another process manipulating it through the master half of the pseudo
>        terminal.  That is, **anything written on the master device is given to the
>        slave device as input and anything written on the slave device is presented as input on the master device.** [emphasis mine]

The simplest way to get your pty working is with `pty.fork()`, which you use like a regular fork. Here's a simple (REALLY minimal) example. Note that if you read more characters than there are available, your process will deadlock: It will try to read from an open pipe, but the only way for the process at the other end to generate output will be if *this* process sends it something!

```
pid, fd = pty.fork()
if pid == 0:
    # We're the child process: Switch to running a command
    os.execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "-n")
    print "Exec failed!!!!"
else:
    # We're the parent process

    # Send something to the child process
    os.write(fd, "Hello, world!\n")

    # Read the terminal's echo of what we typed
    print os.read(fd, 14) ,
    # Read command output
    print os.read(fd, 22)
```

If all goes well you should see this:

```
Hello, world!

     1  Hello, world!
```

Since this is a learning exercise, here's my suggested reading list for you: `man fork`, `man execl`, and python's `subprocess` and `os` modules (since you're already running subprocess, you may already know some of this). Keep in mind the difference, in Unix and in python, between a *file descriptor* (which is just a number) and a `file` object, which is a python object with methods (in C it's a structure or such). Have fun!

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I am not familiar with how to do this. I am following the examples in the documentation, but I am very new to programming, and I am running into issues as to how to open pty and still pipe something into that.

Comment: Fair enough-- the python documentation doesn't really explain anything. I've added a minimal example to get you going.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to do this for learning, you can easily build a fake environment with your own faked passwd-file. You can use some of the built-in python encrypt method to generate passwords. this has the advantage of proper test cases, you know what you are looking for and where you should succeed or fail.

Comment: This has no help on his real question which is "how do I send the password to 'su' from my code?".